# Boot from windows 10 from grub rescue. I have no access to usb/dvd

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate, since other questions mentions access to a USB stick/DVD

I have ubuntu dual boot with windows 10. After uninstalling the ubuntu partition using the windows disk manager, I'm now stuck in the grub rescue menu. How do I boot in windows 10 please? Is a USB stick/DVD the last hope? I need help desperately please

thank you in advance

Comment: The seems like a follow-up question that belongs on the dupe.

Comment: @user535733 OP does not show their posting another question regarding this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? It includes methods which do not rely on A LiveUSB or LiveDVD.  [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)